# Override web page's javascript function using firefox addon sdk

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to override a JS function named `replaceMe` in the web page from my add-on's content script, but I see that the original function implementation always gets executed.

Original HTML contains the following function definition:

```
function replaceMe()
{
  alert('original');
}
```

I'm trying to override it my add-on like (`main.js`):

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url("replacerContent.js")
});
```

Here's what my `replacerContent.js` looks like:

```
this.replaceMe = function()
{
  alert('overridden');
}
```

However, when I run my addon, I always see the text `original` being alerted, meaning the redefinition in replacerContent.js never took effect. Can you let me know why? `replaceMe` not being a [privileged method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Accessing_the_DOM), I should be allowed to override, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is an intentional security between web content and content scripts. If you want to communicate between web content and you have control over the web page as well,  you should use postMessage.

If you don't have control over the web page, there is a hacky workaround. In your content script you can access the window object of the page directly via the global variable `unsafeWindow`:

```
var aliased = unsafeWindow.somefunction;

unsafeWindow.somefunction = function(args) {
    // do stuff
    aliased(args);
}
```

There are two main caveats to this:

1. this is unsafe, so you should never trust data that comes from the page.
2. we have never considered the `unsafeWindow` hack and have plans to remove it and replace it with a safer api.

Comment: This does look like what I might need, but I can't quite get my head around what they [say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_postMessage) to use it for what I need it for. Do you mind writing a sample of how I should use it (like, say, with the example I posted)?

Comment: Eh, that's exactly the link and examples I would send you to. Basically you just send messages from the page using postMessage and listen for them in the content script, as in this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts#Messaging_From_Page_Script_To_Content_Script ...think of the content script as a custom pipe from the page to the main add-on code.

Comment: I think I understood what they mean, but the webpage, in my case, is not something I have any control over. So, what doesn't make sense to me is how sending messages to/from the webpage/content-script will help achieve the effect overriding/redefining a JS function has. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, ok, I assumed you *could* control the page.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on `unsafeWindow` hack, consider using the DOM.

You can create a page script from a content script:

```
var script = 'rwt=function()();';
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.textContent = script;
    document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
});
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can use it in environments without `unsafeWindow`, e. g. chrome extensions.

You can then use postMessage or DOM events to communicate between the page script and the content script.