# In newer versions of Firefox, is it still possible to override a web page's JS function?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing an extension to override a web page's JS function, and started from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725555/override-web-pages-javascript-function-using-firefox-addon-sdk), but the answer does not appear to work in Firefox 42 on Linux.

Next, I tried to use `exportFunction` as described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts), but that also silently failed.

Inside `package.json`, I have added the following sesction.

```
  "permissions": {
      "unsafe-content-script": true
  }
```

Here is my `index.js` file.

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
require("sdk/tabs").on("ready", fixGoogle);

function fixGoogle(tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("google.com") > -1) {
        tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: self.data.url("google-script.js")
        });
    } 
}
```

Here is my current `data/google-script.js`.

```
unsafeWindow.rwt=function(){};
```

Note that manually typing in `rwt=function(){};` to the browser's console achieves the desired effect, as does using a bookmarklet (which requires clicking) but I am writing the plugin to get this automatically every time I use Google.

Is it possible to override the `rwt` page function using a Firefox extension? If so, what is the correct API to use?

Comment: can you just add a plain external script using a small greasemonkey userscript?

Comment: That doesn't work. That was what I tried first.  Silent fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is that the redefinition of the function `rwt` is racing against the original definition and winning. The original runs after and overrides the function I defined, thereby making it look like my redefinition had silently failed.

Once I realized that this was the problem, the easiest hack around it was to add a timeout to the redefinition inside `data/google-script.js`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    unsafeWindow.rwt=function(){};
}, 1000);
```

Thus, the [orignal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736617/391161) is still correct but simply failed to address the race condition.

Answer (score 1):

read the documentation you've linked to, specifically the chapter titled [Expose functions to page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts#Expose_functions_to_page_scripts) - which links to [exportFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.exportFunction)

```
function blah() {}

exportFunction(blah, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: 'rwt'});
```

Comment: I tried that using another function called rwt and that failed silently. I'll try again with a different name when I get back to computer.

Comment: I may be leading you astray, I havn't tried `exportFunction` to **override** an existing function in a web page. The other difference is, I use the above in code loaded via pageMod (`require('sdk/page-mod')`)

Answer (score 0):

Even though content scripts share the DOM, they are otherwise isolated from page scripts. As you correctly surmised, one can use `unsafeWindow` in Firefox to bypass this isolation.

Personally, I don't like the name of `unsafeWindow` for some reason ;)

Therefore I propose another way to do this: make use of the thing that's shared between these scopes, i. e. DOM.

You can create a page script from a content script:

```
var script = 'rwt=function()();';
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.textContent = script;
    document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
});
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can use it in environments without `unsafeWindow`, e. g. chrome extensions.